# Exclude assets for release build type

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, aar

I'm importing an android library in an application built with gradle, like that:

```json
dependencies {
    compile 'com.example:great-lib:0.1-SNAPSHOT'
}
```

This library contains only assets, js, css and images to be used in a webview, with a layout like that:

```
assets/
|-> great.css
|-> great.min.js
|-> great.min.js.map
|-> js/
|   |-> plop.js
|   |-> foo.js
|   ...
|-> img/
|   ...
```

The `js` folder contains source files (to be used with source maps). I would like to include it and the `.map` file for the debug builds, and have only the minified js in release builds, but I can't find a way to do that.

So far I've tried :

```json
android {
    // this doesn't exclude anything
    packageOptions {
        exclude 'assets/js'
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            // this does exclude the js folder, but in both release and debug
            aaptOptions {
                ignoreAssetsPattern "!js"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Any idea if what I want is possible to achieve, and if so how?

(I've also thought of publishing two versions of the library (`great-lib` and `great-lib-debug`), and have the dependency in `debugCompile` and `releaseCompile`, but I'd prefer avoiding that and publishing a single version)

Comment: The `!` **in front** of the subdirectory name is the key. Thank you for this tip.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I ended up doing the following:

```
android.applicationVariants.all { variant ->

  if (variant.name.contains('Release')) {
    // exclude source and sourcemap from release builds
    def noJsSourceTask = task("delete${variant.name}JsSource", type: Delete) {
      delete "${buildDir}/intermediates/assets/${variant.dirName}/js"
      delete "${buildDir}/intermediates/assets/${variant.dirName}/great.min.js.map"
    }
    variant.mergeAssets.finalizedBy noCeJsSourceTask
  }
}
```

It works ok, but there are a few things I don't really like:

- I'm touching at the files produced by a task after it is done (the `finalizedBy`), so it doesn't work well with "up-to-date" checking. But it's only for release builds, I'm doing debug ones more often
- the path of the files to delete is manually built. I'm not sure if it's generic enough to be reused in other projects as-is
- I'm selecting the variants based on their name. I would have liked something more structured.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your solution! I'm still hoping for a solution which is less cumbersome/fragile.

Comment: Trying this in 2019, getting `WARNING: API 'variant.getMergeAssets()' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'variant.getMergeAssetsProvider()'.`. would love an edit that shows the proper newer syntax

Answer (score 26):

I had success with this approach (updated 2019-5-13 for `TaskProvider` support; see edit history for older versions):

```
android {
⋮
    applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        if (variant.buildType.name == 'release') {
            variant.mergeAssetsProvider.configure {
                doLast {
                    delete(fileTree(dir: outputDir, includes: ['**/js', '**/*.js.map']))
                }
            }
        }
    }
⋮
}
```

This should address the issues with @Xavier's answer:

- The deletion is done as part of the variant's `mergeAssets` task so the deletion is reflected in the task's output and up-to-date checking should be unaffected.
- The paths are calculated without magic strings. You may need to adjust the include patterns in case my example is too permissive.
- The variant is being selected by the `buildType` name, which is less problematic than matching the entire variant name (though it is still stringly typed).

Note that this approach also works for `res` files rather than `assets`: just replace `mergeAssets` with `mergeResources`.

Other answers mentioning `packagingOptions` and `aaptOptions` are barking up the wrong tree, as these are scoped to *all* variants (they are defined in the `android` scope, not `buildType` or `productFlavor`).

Comment: Works like a charm!

Comment: Could this be done inside variants.outputs.each? And check the output architecture?

Comment: It's worth mentioning that this code goes _inside_ the `buildTypes` section which is inside the `android` section of your app's build.gradle.

Comment: Thank you so much! You've saved me a lot of time.

Comment: Thanks @Drarok I wish everyone had as much concern and awareness for clarity as you!

Comment: Trying this in 2019, getting `WARNING: API 'variant.getMergeAssets()' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'variant.getMergeAssetsProvider()'.`. would love an edit that shows the proper newer syntax

Comment: Updated to address deprecation warning (`TaskProvider` support) and to note that the code goes in the `android {}` block (it does *not* need to be in the `buildTypes` block).

Answer (score 7):

Gradle provides "aaptOptions, ignoreAssetsPattern" to filter/exclude assets folders and files from release or debug build.

Example for debug build (`js` folder and `great.css` files):

```
debug {            
        aaptOptions {
            ignoreAssetsPattern '!js:!great.css:'
        }
    }
```

Example for release build (`js` folder and `great.css` files):

```
release {
        aaptOptions {
            ignoreAssetsPattern '!js:!great.css:'
        }
    }
```

Comment: ignoreAssetsPattern works for me, but not working on a per-build-type basis - see question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56075155/using-build-specific-aaptoptions-in-android-for-excluding-specific-assets-files

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use proguard. Proguard is include with android studio,obfuscate code,  and remove not used classes, and if you want remove all resources that app not used. Only put in your build.gradle this:

```
 release {

            minifyEnabled true //remove classes, obfuscate code and zipalign
            shrinkResources true //remove resources
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'//autogenerated files
        }
```

This is link information about that:

- http://developer.android.com/tools/help/proguard.html

You can personalize, exclude particular files or ignore particular files

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion to use proguard. I already use proguard, but I can't find any documentation about using it to deleting/not including specific files. Can you be more specific?

Comment: Yep, you should activate shrinkResources in gradle.build, this should remove all resources not used in the project, this should remove all js files, for keep some resources you should create a xml file, inside this file define what files or resources keep from remove. in this [link](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/resource-shrinking) in KeepResources section. After that you should testing well, proguard its complicated to configure and understand. I hope this help you

Comment: I already have `shrinkResources` activated. It does not remove the assets I don't want, since the library that I use, uses those files. I however don't use that part of the library, so I can and want to do without those files.

Comment: Not much information to do that with Proguard, in theory should detect that you do not use. Create a script in build.gradle as they say in the other answer, should be much better solution, sorry for the misunderstanding

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible through a filter.

You could have 2 assets folders though. a main one (src/main/assets) used for both `debug` and `release` and one (src/debug/assets) used only for the debug build.

[source](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/adt-dev/7VLEEeBcDe8)

Comment: Hi, that's not an option for me because the unwanted assets are in a library I use.