# Exclude assets for product flavours?

Tags: android, gradle

This answer deals with removing part of assets depending on Debug/Release
[Exclude assets for release build type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28897450/exclude-assets-for-release-build-type)

But this example does not work with product flavours - the code searches for

/intermediate/assets/release/...

But in my case, using productFlavours, the path is

/intermediate/assets/Flavour_Name/release/...

Could someone help me with modifying gradle code to my case?