# exclude a file from assets directory for release build using gradle build script

Tags: android, gradle, build

This is an Android project. I tried to exclude a resource file under assets folder. I tried

> "aaptOptions {ignoreAssetsPattern "file.json"}"

But it excludes the file for all build variants.

I tried the following, but it still did not work.

> android.variantFilter { variant ->
>       if (variant.buildType.name.equals('release')) {
>           variant.mergeAssets.doLast {
>               delete(fileTree(dir: 'assets/filedir', includes: ['file.json']))
>           }
>       } }

Please help. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score -1):

You can check if you are in `release` or `debug` mode by querying the BuildConfig object. By doing this you can set a conditional verification and exclude the file you want to get rid of for a specific BuildConfig mode:

```
if (BuildConfig.RELEASE) 
{
    // do something, exclude your file
}
```

Alternatively you can compare the `BUILD_TYPE` and use it the same way:

```
if(BuildConfig.BUILD_TYPE.equals("release"))
{
    // do something, exclude your file
}
```

Implement this in the relevant task and you are good to go. Also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29168827/9647266) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39760001/9647266) answers explain how to achieve what you want to do very nicely.

By the way, you can wrap `aaptOptions` in a release closure like this:

```
release {
    aaptOptions {
        ignoreAssetsPattern 'file.json' // Your file pattern
    }
}
```

Comment: `By the way, you can wrap aaptOptions in a release closure like this:` -- can you do the same thing for debug?