# Using Build-specific aaptOptions in Android (for excluding specific Assets files/folders)

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

Been working on an Android Webview app and I've only just now started to use a node_modules folder in there, so naturally I did some research on how to exclude it and I ended up at [this question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28897450/exclude-assets-for-release-build-type)

Tried some of the answers and the one that actually worked the best for me was [the one about aaptOptions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37967667/1959054)

So of course naturally I'm playing around with it, trying to figure out what works, and I succeed at excluding a few folders from the debug apk.

```
            aaptOptions {
                ignoreAssetsPattern '!node_modules:!jsunmin:!.idea:!jade:!css-scss:'
            }
```

And I can indeed confirm that those folders aren't included in the final APK in Android studio! Success!

So then I realize that I can do something a bit clever: when I'm running my app, testing it on my end, debugging it, I like to have certain credentials in certain places automatically put in - I do this with javascript - but obviously I don't want these credentials included in the APKs I might send out into the world -- even though I've already coded it to not input the credentials automatically unless I'm debugging, the credentials are still *actually in the javascript files*, and presumably someone could look in there and see them!

So my idea was to create a file, 'example-creds.js', and use aaptOptions to not include that file, ONLY on release builds, so I came up with something that looks approximately like this (extra details stripped out):

```
android {
    buildTypes {
        release {
            aaptOptions {
                ignoreAssetsPattern '!node_modules:!jsunmin:!.idea:!jade:!css-scss:!example-creds.js:'
            }
        }

        debug {
            aaptOptions {
                ignoreAssetsPattern '!node_modules:!jsunmin:!.idea:!jade:!css-scss:'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**BUT IT DOESN'T WORK!** I've tested it and it seems to run whatever the last-defined aaptOptions is, regardless of the build type. If I put release after debug, I get no example-creds in either build. If I put debug after release, I get example-creds in both.

How can I get what I'm looking for?

Comment: you might need to configure it on project evaluate instead of statically.

Comment: Oof! that doesn't sound like fun

Comment: I'm facing the exact same issue. Did you ever find a solution?

Comment: See [Google issue #301671340](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/301671340).

Answer (score 1):

Generally it should be possible to configure [AaptOptions](https://google.github.io/android-gradle-dsl/current/com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.AaptOptions.html) alike any other configuration block. Try to run that script `afterEvaluate` (which is after those `aaptOptions` had been evaluated):

```
task afterEvaluate {
    doLast {
        applicationVariants.all { variant ->
            variant.outputs.all { output ->
                def pattern = "!node_modules:!jsunmin:!.idea:!jade:!css-scss:"
                if(variant.getBuildType().getName() == 'release') {
                    pattern = pattern + "!example-creds.js:"
                }
                aaptOptions.ignoreAssetsPattern = pattern
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do I paste this code where I currently have my `aaptOptions { }` or somewhere else?

Comment: it's a task, not a configuration.

Comment: Sorry, I'm very unfamiliar with how to build these gradel files so I'm still not sure where to put it. Should it go inside `android {
}` ?

Answer (score 1):

`aaptOptions`'s `ignoreAssetPattern` cannot be set in `afterEvaluate` block. If you try, you will run into this error

```
com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.AgpDslLockedException: It is too late to set ignoreAssetsPattern
It has already been read to configure this project.
Consider either moving this call to be during evaluation,
or using the variant API.
```

The solution is to use the variant API during configuration (also note that `aaptOptions` is depricated and is renamed to `androidResources` AGP 7.1.3 onwards)

```
android {
    buildTypes {
        release {
            androidResources {
                ignoreAssetsPattern '!node_modules:!jsunmin:!.idea:!jade:!css-scss:'
            }
        }

        debug {
            androidResources {
                ignoreAssetsPattern '!node_modules:!jsunmin:!.idea:!jade:!css-scss:'
            }
        }
    }
    androidComponents {
        onVariants(selector().withName("release")) { variant ->
            def pattern = variant.androidResources.ignoreAssetsPattern
            pattern.add("!example-creds.js")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Using AGP 8.1.1. I get this error: `No such property: ignoreAssetsPattern for class: com.android.build.api.variant.impl.AndroidResourcesImpl` with some suggestion: `Possible solutions: ignoreAssetsPatterns`

Answer (score 0):

The existing answers contain a few inaccuracies. Using `AGP 8.1.1` this is the only solution that works:

```
buildTypes {
    // ...
}
androidComponents {
    onVariants(selector().withName('release')) { variant ->
        androidResources.ignoreAssetsPatterns.add('!example-creds.js')
    }
}
androidResources {
    ignoreAssetsPattern = '!node_modules:!jsunmin:!.idea:!jade:!css-scss:'
}
```

First, the `androidResources` is set *outside* the `buildTypes` section. This guarantees that we only set it once. When using different `ignoreAssetsPattern` for multiple build types, the *last* declared build type always wins. This looks like a **bug**, see [issues/301671340](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/301671340). `Gradle` should at least produce a warning when inactive build types overwrite a shared value...

Second, we do not update any property on the `variant` itself. Instead, we alter the *shared* `ignoreAssetsPatterns` list. (Use `addAll()` to add multiple patterns in one go.)