# Set noCompress for only one productFlavor

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I'm trying to set `androidResources.noCompress` for only one product flavor

When I try this

```
flavorDimensions "ring"
productFlavors {
    innerRing {
        dimension "ring"
    }
    outerRing {
        dimension "ring"
        androidResources {
            noCompress 'so'
        }
    }
}
```

Both `innerRing` and `outerRing` end up with `.so` files uncompressed. I believe this is due to gradle configuring all the product flavors statically. (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56075155/using-build-specific-aaptoptions-in-android-for-excluding-specific-assets-files))

But when I try to change `noCompress` afterEvaluate

```
afterEvaluate {
    android.applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        def ring = variant.getProductFlavors().get(0).name
        if (ring == "outerRing") {
            println("Don't compress .so files for outer ring build")
            android.androidResources.noCompress = ['so']
        }
    }
}
```

I get this error

```
com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.AgpDslLockedException: 
It is too late to modify internalNoCompressList
It has already been read to configure this project.
Consider either moving this call to be during evaluation,
or using the variant API.
```

How can I use the variant API to fix this?
Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are on AGP 7.2

```
android {
...
    androidComponents {
        onVariants(selector().all()) { variant ->
            if(variant.name.startsWith("outerRing")) {
                variant.androidResources.noCompress.add('so')
            }
        }
    }
...
}
```

If AGP is below 7.2 then from the documentation theoretically the following code should work, but I've had no success with it

```
android {
...
    androidComponents {
        onVariants(selector().all()) { variant ->
            if(variant.name.startsWith("outerRing")) {
                def aaptParams = variant.androidResources.aaptAdditionalParameters
                aaptParams.add("-0")
                aaptParams.add("so")
            }
        }
    }
...
}
```